# Dropdowns navbar in mobile version won't drop

Tags: javascript

The code is adding a class to an element that allows the user to open up the hamburger on a mobile device, but it has an ID and we use three elements, and the code is written for one specific ID.

We need that code to work for classes so the user can open all three of the buttons in the hamburger

I've tried adding more IDs but that's about it. 
I've watched hours of tutorials and I still can't figure it out.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0047/9274/6077/t/2/assets/app.min.js?603193

Here is link for clean the code: 
https://html-cleaner.com/js/

```
d.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var e, t = d;
    (e = t).getAttribute("id") !== n.id.shop || .hasClass(e, n.cls.showing) ? .removeClass(e, n.cls.showing) : _.addClass(e, n.cls.showing)
}, !1)


id: {
    account: "nav__mobile-account",
    menu: "nav__mobile-menu",
    nav: "nav",
    nav_mobile: "nav__mobile",
    nav_mobile_overlay: "nav-mobile-overlay",
    nav_toggle_icon: "nav-toggle-icon",
    shop: "nav__mobile-shop",
    searchInput: "searchInput",
    searchBtn: "searchBtn",
    headerPanel: "headerPanel",
    searchForm: "searchForm"
}
}, t = document.getElementById(n.id.account), e = document.body, i = document.getElementById(n.id.menu), o = document.getElementById(n.id.nav), s = document.getElementById(n.id.nav_mobile), r = document.getElementById(n.id.nav_mobile_overlay), a = document.getElementById(n.id.nav_toggle_icon), c = document.getElementById(n.id.searchInput), l = document.getElementById(n.id.searchBtn), d = document.getElementById(n.id.shop), u = document.getElementById(n.id.headerPanel), h = document.getElementById(n.id.searchForm), f = window.innerWidth <= 767, p = f ? "mobile" : "desktop";

function m(e) {
    e.getAttribute("id") === n.id.menu ? (_.addClass(s.parentNode, n.cls.menu_is_active), _.addClass(i, n.cls.active), _.removeClass(s.parentNode, n.cls.account_is_active), _.removeClass(t, n.cls.active)) : (_.addClass(s.parentNode, n.cls.account_is_active), _.addClass(t, n.cls.active), _.removeClass(s.parentNode, n.cls.menu_is_active), _.removeClass(i, n.cls.active))
}

function g() {
    _.removeClass(o, n.cls.active), _.removeClass(r, n.cls.active)
}

function v() {
    _.mq({
        view: "desktop",
        callback: function() {
            "desktop" !== p && (f = !(p = "desktop"), _.hasClass(o, n.cls.active) && g(), _.hasClass(d, n.cls.showing) && _.removeClass(d, n.cls.showing))
        }
    }), _.mq({
        view: "mobile",
        callback: function() {
            "mobile" !== p && (p = "mobile", f = !0, g())
        }
    })
}
return window.scrollY, window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    95 <= window.scrollY ? e.classList.add(n.cls.header_panel_hidden) : e.classList.remove(n.cls.header_panel_hidden)
}), _.windowResize(v), a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    _.addClass(o, n.cls.active), _.addClass(r, n.cls.active)
}, !1), r.addEventListener("click", function() {
    g()
}, !1), t.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var e = t;
    m(e)
}, !1), i.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var e = i;
    m(e)
}, !1), d.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var e, t = d;
    (e = t).getAttribute("id") !== n.id.shop || _.hasClass(e, n.cls.showing) ? _.removeClass(e, n.cls.showing) : _.addClass(e, n.cls.showing)
}, !1)
```

Some html code that we're using

```
<ul class="nav__left">

              <li id="nav__mobile-shop" class="nav__item nav__item--has-dropdown">
                <span style="line-height:74px;height:74px;font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" class="nav__btn nav__item">
                  Read
                </span>
                <ul class="nav__item-dropdown nav__item-dropdown-shop">
                   <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="events.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Events</a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="newsletters.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Our News</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="articles.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Press</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

              <li id="nav__mobile-shop" class="nav__item nav__item--has-dropdown">
                <span style="line-height:74px;height:74px;font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" class="nav__btn nav__item">
                  Science
                </span>
                <ul class="nav__item-dropdown nav__item-dropdown-shop">
                   <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="product_overview.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Overview of Product</a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="quality_control.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Quality Control</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="research_dev.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Research and Development</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

              <li id="nav__mobile-shop" class="nav__item nav__item--has-dropdown">
                <span style="line-height:74px;height:74px;font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" class="nav__btn nav__item">
                  FAQ
                </span>
                <ul class="nav__item-dropdown nav__item-dropdown-shop">
                   <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="about.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">About Us</a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="nav__item nav__item">
                    <a href="common_categories.php" class="nav__btn nav__btn--in-dropdown">Common Questions</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend reading [mcve] to learn how to properly post a question.

Comment: Hi @Mister Salass - welcome to stack overflow. I think you need to bring a bit more to us here, presenting us with a huge block of minified code and saying 'yeah go format this yourself and figure it out' is a little much to ask random strangers.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post! It still seems that this code is generated somehow, (perhaps babel?)  as there seem to be many things here a human would not think of doing (looking at !1 for example) 


Is there some original source code? Or is this copied from somewhere? Sorry, but I am personally finding this code extremely difficult to figure out. (nested ternary operators, I have no idea what !1 is supposed to accomplish)

Comment: Ahh yes, after some checking, !1 is minified 'false'. Which makes sense. But why are you trying to edit minified code?

Comment: @Slabgorb this is copied from the link given in the description, to be honest i dont have a clue, never worked with js, and this navbar is the only thing thats not working so far, thats why i came here for the first time in my life, maybe someone will understand, a boy can dream, can he? thats pretty much it, if its bad, i'm sorry for wasting your time, good sir

Comment: No no, not wasting my time, just trying to figure out things. It appears as though you are doing something with Shopify here. And in the end, some code gets hosted on their content delivery network, or CDN. But was this you or someone on your team making this code before it gets sent to Shopify? (I have never used Shopify, guessing it is a 'make my ecommerce site' tool.

Comment: Some explanantion: to save bandwidth/networking costs, often the source code that programmers write gets 'minified' or 'uglified'. This is a process that generates the equivalent code, but makes everything as small and as tight as possible. This is not code you want to edit. The code you want to edit is BEFORE all that happens. Having Shopify in the mix means that the code could be autogenerated by Shopify based on you doing something in the Shopify interface, we just don't know.

Comment: it is taken from a page that uses shopify, there must be a better way of doing this, maybe the html edit will help a little, its only working for one of the IDs, because its IDs, and it must be byClassName, so it fetches all of the elements with dropdown items

Comment: Are you looking for `document.getElementsByClassName("example");`  perhaps?

Comment: yes, its `getElementById` and we need to replace it with the `getElementsByClassname` one, so the code works for all the elements in the html code